# How to add SysWOW64 support to the Windows 10 Preinstallation Environment? (version 1607)

Tags: windows, windows-10, winpe

So I created a [custom Windows 10 Setup disk](https://mega.nz/#F!5bwgEQ6Y!FqvcsaSxWDfDBEeSJ1sEuQ) that includes the [AOMEI Windows Preinstallation Environment](https://www.aomeitech.com/pebuilder/help/?pebuilder) (I chose it because it already includes Windows Explorer). I copied the files from the AOMEI Preinstallation Environment to the existing boot.wim on the iso (index:2) and I replaced files already to the boot.wim (otherwise explorer wouldn't run) using a SYSTEM command prompt (because otherwise I would get not enough permissions error) and now it can be used to install both Windows 10 Home and Pro version 1607 as well as for recovery purposes. I have created both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. I want to expand it by adding additional software but some of the software that I want to install only has 32-bit versions and I have read that the Windows Preinstallation Environment doesn't support SysWOW64 support by default. So how do I add SysWOW64 support to the Windows 10 Preinstallation Environment vbersion 1607? Boot.wim is Windows 10 version 1607 and install.wim is also Windows 10 version 1607 (I used version 1607 because the AOMEI Preinstallation Environment is also version 1607 and it wouldn't work otherwise)

Edit: By the way one major problem I have is that the 64-bit version of QtWeb (that is included by default with the AOMEI Preinstalation Environment) doesn't support secure connections (https) but the 32-bit version does. So I want to install the 32-bit version to the 64-bit media but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a detailed description for creating such a WinPE environment
in the article
[Adding WoW64 to WinPE 10 for 32-bit app support - V2](http://reboot.pro/topic/21197-adding-wow64-to-winpe-10-for-32-bit-app-support-v2/).

The described procedure requires the 64-bit Win10PE SE image by
[The Oven](http://theoven.org/index.php?board=36.0),
but does not link to it.

You will find this image at the
[Win10PE SE Downloads Page](http://win10se.cwcodes.net/Compressed/).

Comment: How to export registry entries from winpe images?

Comment: Find or extract the [registry hives](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/256986/windows-registry-information-for-advanced-users) in the image and use `regedit`: Click `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, then menu *File > Load Hive* to browse it.

Comment: Also can I do this without deleting X:\Windows\WinSxS because I have an already modified image that is not mine (I made it using the [AOMEI PE Builder](https://www.aomeitech.com/pebuilder/help/?pebuilder))

Comment: You could try without deleting it. I don't have experience with this procedure, so don't know if this step is essential.

Comment: Apparently I need permission from TrustedInstaller in order to copy the files. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Try doing the copy from a Command Prompt using [psexec -s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

Comment: Or boot it and use `regedit` to export the keys.

Comment: Even as SYSTEM I get access denied (sometimes). Wait that's illegal. But I discovered [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) and [this plugin](https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2407) that allows me to run any program as TrustedInstaller (whoami command still says SYSTEM) and bypass all restrictions.